# htaccess rewrite for domains using Wordpress with non-www and https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, uri

I am looking for a .htaccess configuration that applies to domains using non-www and https (SLL) and Wordpress**

After spending hours on stack overflow and hundreds of combinations, I have not managed to find a htaccess file that can do all I need.

This htaccess file must do the following:

1. Rewrite **www to non-www**
2. Rewrite **http to https**
3. **Preserve URI strings** (the url part on your site)
4. Enable wordpress to handle pretty permalinks.

> - http:// www. example .com  --> https:// example .com
> - https:// www. example.com  --> https:// example .com
> - http:// example .com   --> https:// example .com
> - https:// example .com  --> https:// example .com **(must ignore)**
> - http:// www. example .com/foo.html --> https:// example .com/ foo.html
> - https:// www. example .com/foo.html    --> https:// example .com/ foo.html
> - http:// example .com/foo.html  --> https:// example .com/ foo.html
> - https:// example .com/foo.html --> https:// example .com/ foo.html **(must ignore)**

Comment: If you are trying to post information, please write a question, and check the `Answer your own question` box at the bottom of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally managed to solve the problem on my own**

Add the following code to your .htaccess file.

```
    # BEGIN Rewrite so the site works with www and without.
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301]
    # END Rewrite so the site works with www and without.

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

Ps. It might also work for sites using www. but I have not tested this.

Hope this helps someone! :-)